# Asking a question about HTTP and HTTPS ports for hosting a website

Tags: support

I'm trying to figure out what StackExchange site would handle questions related to software ports, and their purpose?

Comment: For port see http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml .. else just ask what you have in mind !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without seeing your actual question it's difficult to say for sure as there are likely more than one.

Why don't you just ask your question on Server Fault. If it's good and topical it'll get an answer. If it's good but not topical it'll likely get  migrated to a place where it is topical. If it's a crappy question it'll get put on hold and eventually closed.